# How to use this manipulator

Tags: c++, manipulators

This is a exercise for school, so please provide just hints and no complete examples ;-)

I have my own manipulator:

```
template<typename T, typename Tr=char_traits<T> >
ios_base& toggle(basic_ios<T,Tr>& io)
{
    if(io.flags() & ios::scientific)
    { io.unsetf(ios::scientific); io.flags(ios::fixed); }
    else { io.unsetf(ios::fixed); io.flags(ios::scientific); }
    return io;
 }
```

I wrote this, because I have to write a manipulator with the form `ios_base& my_manip(basic_ios&)`.

If I use it like this (without using return value):

```
toggle(cout);
```

... that works fine. But if I use it like that:

```
toggle(cout) << 54444.6456555 << endl;
```

That does not work (Because std::ios_base does not have operator<<() as stated below).

In general I do not get what `ios_base& my_manip(basic_ios&)` could be useful for... Do you have a hint/example?

---

You guys already helped me a lot! What I still do NOT understand, is the motivation to pass a `basic_ios` and give back `ios_base` (because that is suggested to do in the exercise I have to solve...). What could be a possible scenario to use this???

Comment: Hint: Take a look at the overloads of `operator<<` for `std::ostream`s: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt

Comment: Hint2: An `ios_base` has no `operator>>` nor `operator<<` defined. That's why `toggle(cout) << "something"` doesn't work.

Comment: +1 This is a refreshing example of how to ask a homework question.

Comment: Hint 3 (spoiler alert ;) Take a look at [how `endl` is defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)

Comment: @ DyP: Sorry, but your spoiler alert hint does not help me much :-( The point is, that I really should define the function as `ios_base& my_manip(basic_ios&)` (even though I do not get what it could be useful for...)

Comment: @Michael The point is that `std::ostream` has several `operator<<` overloads that take function pointers and calls them. Using manipulators like `std::endl`, `std::hex` or your own is typically done by calling the `operator<<` (or `operator>>` for `istream`s) of the stream and passing a *pointer to the manipulator function*. Note that function names decay to pointers to those functions.

Comment: by the way: is there a difference between std::basic_ostream and std::ostream? If not, why are there two names?

Comment: @Michael `std::ostream` is a typedef for `std::basic_ostream<char>`. There's also `std::wostream`, a typedef for `std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>`.

Comment: *"What I still do NOT understand, is the motivation to pass a `basic_ios` and give back `ios_base`"* Nobody spotted that yet :D -- It's an error if the manipulator is intended to be used as `stream<<toggle`. It has to be either `basic_ios<T,Tr>& my_manip(basic_ios<T,Tr>&)` or `ios_base& my_manip(ios_base&)`. In your case, I think the base class `ios_base` is sufficient, it already provides the necessary functionality and is therefore the more general choice (see [this class diagram](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io)). When using `ios_base`, you don't need a function template.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the manipulator is that it returns an `std::ios_base&` rather than a `std::ostream&` you can write to. You *could* change the manipulator to take an `std::ostream&` as parameter and return the reference received. However, the output stream class defines output operators which take pointers to functions:

```
std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<< (std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) { ... }
```

That is, you can just insert manipulators pretty much the way you would do it with, e.g., `std::hex`:

```
std::cout << std::hex << 123 << ' ' << std::dec << 123 << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the issue which Dietmar addressed: `io.flags()
& ios::scientific` does not return a `bool`, and the conversion
to `bool` probably doesn't do what you want.  You need something
along the lines of:

```
if ( (io.flags() & ios::floatfield) == ios::fixed ) {
    io.setf( ios::scientific, ios::floatfield );
} else if ( (io.flags() & ios::floatfield) == ios::scientific ) {
    io.setf( ios::fixed, ios::floatfield );
} else {
    //  Whatever you want to happen first time around...
}
```

Despite being part of a variable with a type named `...flags`,
`floatfield` is not a flag, but a field which can take on at
least three values: `fixed`, `scientific` and its default value
in which neither of these are set.  (`basefield` and
`adjustfield` behave similarly.)

Note too the use of the two argument form of `ios::setf`; it is
designed especially for these bitfield format parameters, and
resets the bits in its second argument before setting the ones
in its first.

I might add that you probably do *not* want to call `io.flags`
in your manipulator; this sets *all* of the formatting flags to
the value you give, effectively resetting all other formatting
flags.  If you're only outputting floating point, this may not
be a problem (although `showpos`, `showpoint`, `uppercase` and
possibly `unitbuf` might be relevant), but you never know.